# (Game of Life) How to loop through outer layer of a matrix without checking outside of it, simultaneously checking for neighbors?

Tags: algorithm, logic, matrix

Each point in the matrix represents a cell, living or dead. I have to count how many ALIVE neighbors each cell has. I have a function that does the job, but it checks for cells outside its boundary. I don't know how I can simultaneously check for neighbors and keep track of edges without doing a massive amount of if-else statements. Here's my implementations for reference:

```
void Neighbours(int rows, 
            int cols, cell world[rows][cols], 
            int neighbors[rows][cols]) {

//Loop through each cell in the matrix. 
for(int rCell = 0; rCell < rows; rCell++){
  for(int cCell = 0; cCell < cols; cCell++) {
    //Reset neighbor count for each cell.
    neighbors[rCell][cCell] = 0;
    //Check cell status in cell's vicinity of each cell. 
    for(int surroundR = -1; surroundR <= 1; surroundR++){
      for(int surroundC = -1; surroundC <= 1; surroundC ++) {
        //CONDITIONS
        //1. If the cell is alive,
        //2. if the cell is not itself,
        //3. if it does exist within the boundaries of the matrix.
        if(field[rCell - surroundR][cCell - surroundC].status == ALIVE) {
          if(!(surroundR  == 0 && surroundC  == 0) && (rCell-surroundR < rows) && (cCell-surroundC < cols) && (cCell-surroundC  >= 0) && (rCell-surroundR  >= 0)) {
            neighbors[rCell][cCell] += 1;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  } 
}
}
```